# Is it possible for PowerBI to recognize the names in a single column but treat them as separate?

Tags: powerbi, dax

Bit of a weird or vague question but can´t find a better way to name it.

Here´s the issue. I´ve got a row of data. In this row there´s a column that contains the names of members of a project. Is it possible for PowerBI to recognize the names in a column and treat them as separate? More explanation in my data attached.

As you can see there is a task assigned to four people. I would like to judge how buys someone is by the amount of tasks the person is assigned. However I am kinda stuck, as the data is in one column on a row. Is there any way that PowerBI recognizes that Dave has two tasks while Mari has only one?

[image: s1]

Comment: In the Query Editor you could split that column on the semicolon delimiter into new Rows.  Then you would have just a single row per member.

Comment: **Is there any way that PowerBI recognizes that Dave has two tasks while Mari has only one?** - yes DAX can read from the comma-separated values as long as you maintain a separate table of project members. If you have that, follow this [link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302471/how-to-put-tables-in-stack-overflow) and post the sample data.

Comment: @smpa01 That's great cause I do have such a table. How do I make DAX read from the comma-seperated values?

Comment: please post sample data in a table format following the link and mention what is the desired output based on that.

Comment: You can do this in DAX but just because you can doesn't mean you should. Your data needs reshaping in PQ first to create a more logical data model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you should create another table with project members separate, like:

| Members |
| --- |
| Dave |
| Mari |
| etc. |

Then add field *Members* from this table to visualization pane.
Next write DAX measure calculating tasks number for every project member:

```
Tasks Number = 
VAR _Member =
    SELECTEDVALUE('Members'[Member])
RETURN
CALCULATE(
    COUNTA('Table'[Task name]),
    CONTAINSSTRING('Table'[Project members], _Member)
)
```

and add it to the same pane as previous field.

Using `VAR` in this measure is necessary because `CONTAINSSTRING()` can't get values from different tables.
Also there is no need to create a relationship between these two tables.

But I would advice you to normalize this table using Power Query if it is able for your data model. To do this you should:

1. Open Power Query by pressing `Transform data`;
2. Select *Project members* column and press `Split by delimiter` in context menu (choose
   semicolon as a delimiter);
3. Select all splitted columns add choose
   `Transform` - `Unpivot columns` in horizontal menu;
4. Delete *Attribute* column and rename *Value* column.